# JavaScript call default value of class

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

I'm tyring to give a default value to a JavaScript Class.

i.e.

```
class tr{
    constructor(value=null){
        this.type = typeof value;
        this.val = value;
        this.start = new Date();
    }
}
```

Now, if I want to get value I should use something like that:

```
let trVar = new tr;
console.log(trVar.val);
```

But I want to call value as default when I call just `trVar` itself.
I mean:

```
console.log(trVar);
```

This should be value.

I don't want to remove type and start.

Thanks.

Comment: The value of `trVar` is the reference to the object; a variable can only have one value. You could add a `toString()` method to the class so that when `trVar` is coerced to a string you'd get the value, though that is only a limited solution.

Comment: I know that, at my case it returns object, but is there any solution to call a default value if doesn't call it's case. I think my question would be an object issue(Object's default value)

Comment: It is really unclear what is it you want. please try to rephrase your question. do you want eventually to evalutate `trVar` as `this.value` ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want

Comment: JavaScript does not provide a way to do that. In an expression, `trVar` by itself means "the value of the variable named *trVar*".

Comment: Interesting, because String works like that. You can do something like `myString = "my string"`; and then expect `myString` to be `"my string"` when used, but can also do `myString.length();`. Wonder if there is a way to extend String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is an anti pattern to OOP.

When you chose that OOP route, you should use it as intended.

If you'd like to turn an object instance into a single variable simply bind a variable to point to that value you want. or, don't use OOP.

you could create a function that returns only what you want and store whatever you dont want inside it. that would work better for you I guess.

Comment: String works this way.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**

I am not sure why you'd want to do that but, `let trVar = new tr` trVal here is the reference to the instance of tr.

**Perhaps:**

What you are trying to do is get the `val` field when you instantiate the `tr` class. Unfortunately the `new` keyword creates a new instance of which it's reference is stored  in `trVar`... So to only get the value out of the instance you could perhaps do this:
`let trVar = (new tr).val;`.